# package domain, role and user on sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I am new to sitecore.

I have a question regarding packaging Domain and Roles on sitecore (we are using sitecore 6.3.1).

I am packaging content from our dev box to stage and I would like to transfer the Domain, Roles and user created on dev to stage.

The package designer shows a button called 'Security Accounts'. I added the specific user \ who belong to the specific domain and role.

On installing the package to stage site, it throws an error 'blah domain not found, cannot create user'.

So the question is, do i have to create a domain manually on the stage server before I install the user? or is there a way where I can copy the domain and roles to create the user?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your target solution doesn't have the domain the user lives in, you'll have to create it manually. However, the roles can be transferred via package the same way as users. If the user A is in role B, and you don't add role B to the package, there should not be any error - simply the user A won't be a member of the role B on target environment.

Answer (score 6):

I have discovered that the domains are stored in /App_Config/Security/Domains.config and you can migrate between installations simply by copying or editing this file.

Or you can create the domains manually via the Security Domain tool.

Either way the domain must exist before you can install a package with users or roles.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the answer Yan comes with would work with domains.

But you might need to have the Domain(s) in a package which you install first, or have it as the first "part" of your package, so it gets installed first.